# Is it implant into or onto?

Tags: grammar, phrases

Is it implant into or onto? I am asking, because the example I have in mind seems to invite the use of the alternative wording "implant onto".

Here's the example:

> The surgeons implanted a mole onto her left cheek.

Because the mole is on the surface of the skin or slightly inside the skin, but near the surface, I am wondering if "onto" is correct.

Comment: Let me get this straight -- the surgeons *added* a mole on her skin?  This is unusual as people usually have surgery to remove (cancerous or unsightly) moles.

Comment: How would you say it?